# Article Share API from LinkedIn Throwing error

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to make a simple share button LinkedIn using the article share API. It's pretty straight foward, or so I thought.

When using the domain's `href`, it works:

https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsp156.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/portal

I can even make it to another page:

https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsp156.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/portal/servicos

However, if I try another page:

https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsp156.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/portal/servicos/informacao?servico=3832

It brings up a error. Looking at the console doesn't really help that much, and at the network tab all the requests return 200.

I tried removing the query parameters, although the page doesn't work without them, and still, didn't worked

@edit:
Even the LinkedIn official inspector of pages can recognize the page, now I'm really confused:

https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/https:%2F%2Fsp156.prefeitura.sp.gov.br%2Fportal%2Fservicos%2Finformacao%3Fservico=3832

Anyone has idea on what's happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Linkedin works in mysterious ways

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks.

Comment: To be honest, I have tried to figure out why it didnt work and I couldnt too. I tried several different things like double url encoding among other stuff.

Comment: I appreciate your time, regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you are sharing contains a `?` character.  You need to escape that character using [URL-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).  So, this is what you should want...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsp156.prefeitura.sp.gov.br%2Fportal%2Fservicos%2Finformacao%3Fservico%3D3832
```

Notice how the `?` is rendered here as `%3F`.  URL's should only have one `?` at all, because that indicates that `$_GET` data is going to proceed that mark.  With two of them, the server doesn't know and gets confused!

***Looks good to me now!***

[image]

In case you want to know more: **[Official LinkedIn Share Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**

Comment: Yeah, i found that eventually, and that's weird considering that i doesn't get confused with the slashes '/' but it does with the question mark. Anyway, thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

If you browse directly to the landing page of in debug mode you will see that it is returning the error 200 and not linked in.

https://sp156.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/portal/servicos/informacao?servico=3832

Ops, parece que este serviço não existe, busque um serviço na lista ao lado.

Which Google translate says is Oops, it looks like this service doesn't exist, look for a service in the list on the side.

LinkedIn has to redirect to a known good page, that is why the other two resolve.
I did notice that there is a login option on that page, is perhaps the page only accessible post login?

Comment: That's not right, first, because the page exist, thats a error on the page. Second, with a service that is actually working:

https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle/?url=https://sp156.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/portal/servicos/informacao?servico=805

also throw the same error.

Comment: The linkedin inspector itself can recognize the page, but i can't share it:

https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/https:%2F%2Fsp156.prefeitura.sp.gov.br%2Fportal%2Fservicos%2Finformacao%3Fservico=3832